# How can I force Rails to precompile SCSS stylesheets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to run a CRM gem that is clearly not ready for primetime. I'm trying to contribute back to the project by adding all of the things I'm finding that's wrong with the program.

But I am stuck on an asset precompile issue. I'm about a mile wide and an inch deep on the Asset Pipeline. I have run:

bundle exec rake assets:precompile

but when trying to bring the application up in a browser, the following error is written to the log file:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (print.css isn't precompiled):
    5:     %title Not Ready Yet CRM
    6:     == <!-- #{controller.controller_name} : #{controller.action_name} -->
    7:     = stylesheet_link_tag :application
    8:     = stylesheet_link_tag :print, :media => 'print'
    9:     %style= yield :styles
    10:
    11:     = javascript_include_tag :application
```

The actual file in the gem is NOT called "print.css". It's called "print.css.scss".

Where do I tell Rails to pick up these files in Asset precompilation? And if I do, will it just automatically know how to interpret SCSS files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add it to `config.assets.precompile` in config/application.rb or `config/environments/production.rb`.

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
config.assets.precompile += %w( print.css )
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that this line exists in the gem itself, but apparently the asset pipeline requires that you know what needs to be precompiled in gems that you're using as engines.

I'm sure there must be some additional Railties.engines settings to handle this that I'm overlooking.

Comment: "all non-JS/CSS are already added" Is SCSS not non-CSS? or Coffeescript non-JS?

Comment: scss and coffeescript files are considered as css and js. A file like `example.css.scss` is basically a css file with a scss preprocessor. Except for external libs, people only write scss or sass now in rails apps. It would be terrible if the default was just to compile allll of them.